# Replacing values by values of a different dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have this kind of dataframe (df1):

```
     Code    ID_CODE     value_1   value_2    value_3
     HA09U    98_ 10      57.80      NA          NA
     HA09U    98_ 11      57.80      NA          NA
     HA09U    98_ 12      57.80      NA          NA 
     MB03L    99_ 10        NA      90.77        NA
     MB03L    99_ 11        NA      90.77        NA
     MB03L    99_ 12        NA      90.77        NA
     KE17P    100_ 10      68.44    76.05        72.01
     KE17P    100_ 11      68.44    76.05        72.01
     KE17P    100_ 12      68.44    76.05        72.01
```

I want to replace the value of ALL variables (value_1, value_2 and value_3) of the person that includes NAs by adding the values from my second dataframe (df2):

```
     Code    value_1   value_2    value_3
    HA09U     90.35     89.84      90.07
    MB03L     66.94     79.62      73.77
```

The result should be:

```
      Code    ID_CODE     value_1    value_2    value_3
     HA09U    98_ 10       90.35      89.84      90.07
     HA09U    98_ 11       90.35      89.84      90.07
     HA09U    98_ 12       90.35      89.84      90.07 
     MB03L    99_ 10       66.94      79.62      73.77
     MB03L    99_ 11       66.94      79.62      73.77
     MB03L    99_ 12       66.94      79.62      73.77
     KE17P    100_ 10      68.44      76.05      72.01
     KE17P    100_ 11      68.44      76.05      72.01
     KE17P    100_ 12      68.44      76.05      72.01
```

I tried to use some merge and bind_rows function, this one took me the closest:

```
df1$value_1[df1$Code == df2$Code] <- df2$value_1
```

But it did not worked and somehow messed up the dataframe.

Using this code

```
d1 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "Code" )
```

Adds three new colums with the values of df2, but the values of KE17P (the person that already has complete data) is missing. So I am really looking for a replacing function.

Comment: `left_join()` from `dplyr` will give you what you want.

Comment: I tried `df3<- left_join(df1, df2, by = "Code" )` and it worked so far... but adds the values from df2 by adding three new columns and not replacing the old values in the original columns

Comment: So drop the original columns from `df1` before you do the `left_join`...

Comment: Yeah but the original datafram is much more complex and has multiple IDs and rows that doesn't exist in df2. So if I drop them they would be lost, because in the new columns they all have NAs

Comment: Then rewrite your question so that it includes all salient features of the problem.

Comment: I did, thank you. Hope you can help me anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a join in `data.table` (Here, we assume the `NA` columns are `numeric` class and not `logical`)

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep('^value_\\d+$', names(df1), value = TRUE)
setDT(df1)[df2, (nm1) := mget(paste0('i.', nm1)), on = .(Code)]
```

-output

```
df1
#    Code ID_CODE value_1 value_2 value_3
#1: MB03L  99_ 10   66.94   79.62   73.77
#2: MB03L  99_ 11   66.94   79.62   73.77
#3: MB03L  99_ 12   66.94   79.62   73.77
#4: MB03L  99_ 13   66.94   79.62   73.77
#5: MB03L  99_ 14   66.94   79.62   73.77
#6: MB03L  99_ 15   66.94   79.62   73.77
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = 'Code') %>%
  transmute(Code, ID_CODE, across(ends_with('.x'), ~ 
     coalesce(get(str_replace(cur_column(),"\\.x", ".y")), .))) %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_remove(., '\\.x'), starts_with('value_'))
```

-output

```
#    Code ID_CODE value_1 value_2 value_3
#1 MB03L  99_ 10   66.94   79.62   73.77
#2 MB03L  99_ 11   66.94   79.62   73.77
#3 MB03L  99_ 12   66.94   79.62   73.77
#4 MB03L  99_ 13   66.94   79.62   73.77
#5 MB03L  99_ 14   66.94   79.62   73.77
#6 MB03L  99_ 15   66.94   79.62   73.77
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Code = c("MB03L", "MB03L", "MB03L", "MB03L", "MB03L", 
"MB03L"), ID_CODE = c("99_ 10", "99_ 11", "99_ 12", "99_ 13", 
"99_ 14", "99_ 15"), value_1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), value_2 = c(90.77, 90.77, 90.77, 
90.77, 90.77, 90.77), value_3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")


df2 <- structure(list(Code = c("HA09U", "MB03L"), value_1 = c(90.35, 
66.94), value_2 = c(89.84, 79.62), value_3 = c(90.07, 73.77)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: @psycho95 as the column names are the same in 'df1' and df2', the df2 columns are identified with prefix i.values_1, i.values_2, etc.

Comment: I receive `value for ‘i.’ not found`

Comment: @psycho95 have you loaded the `library(data.table)` .  Please use the data in my post and try it again. thanks

Comment: I worked with your data, but somehow doesn't with my dataframe

Comment: @psycho95 I updated with tidyverse approach.  Not sure why it is not working for you

Comment: I restarted R and tried it again, now it worked, don't know why it didn*t before... Thank you very much!